# Google Bar Chart - custom Legend text with total values & column wise total for Table chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, legend-properties, column-chart

i would like get the total value of Grades in Stacked Bar Graph Legend. picture attached how i wud like to have... for the following working snippet.

and also the Column wise Total for the Table Chart...

i think this can be done with following but how to get it done..

data.setFormattedValue(i, 0, key + ' (' + val + ')');

[image: Current look]

[image: Expected result]

can have something like this.. when mouseover one location on Bar... need to show all the grades values in single annotation..??

[image: Mouseover On Bar for the location]

is it possible to have the different values in highlighted places like in below picture? circle B is overall total of Grade1 in graph is correct. and circle A the tooltip total should show for that particular locations total of every Grade's annotation like below.

```
['Location', 'Company', 'Grade1',{ role: 'annotation' }, 'Grade2',{ role: 'annotation' }, 'Grade3',{ role: 'annotation' }, 'Bal-Grade', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
```

[image]

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  drawMainDashboard();
});

function drawMainDashboard() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard_division1'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 1,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Company Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div1',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Location Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var columnchrt = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
       title: "Locations  charts",
       width: 850,
       height: 500,
       legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
       bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },
       isStacked: true,
       focusTarget: 'category',
       aggregationTarget: 'category',
       explorer: {keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: 10.0}
  }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'Table',
  'containerId': 'table_div',
  'options': {
      showRowNumber: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      allowHtml: true
  },
  'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', calcTotals);
          
          function calcTotals() {
                // get filtered data table from table chart
                var dt = table.getDataTable();
                
                // build aggregation and view columns
                var aggColumns = [];
                var viewColumns = [0];
                for (var i = 2; i < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
                      if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) {
                        if (dt.getColumnType(i) === 'number') {
                          if (dt.getColumnRole(i) !== 'annotation') {
                            addAggColumn(i);
                            if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 2) {
                              viewColumns.push(i - 1);
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                function addAggColumn(index) {
                    aggColumns.push({
                      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
                      column: index,
                      label: dt.getColumnLabel(index),
                      type: dt.getColumnType(index)
                    });
                  }
                // aggregate data table
                var agg = google.visualization.data.group(
                  dt,
                  [0],
                  aggColumns
                );
                var aggTotal = google.visualization.data.group(
                  dt,
                  [{
                    column: 0,
                    label: 'Total',
                    modifier: function (val) {
                      return 'Total';
                    },
                    type: 'string'
                  }],
                  aggColumns
                );
                
                dt = dt.toDataTable();
                dt.addRow(['Total', '--', aggTotal.getValue(0, 1), aggTotal.getValue(0, 2), aggTotal.getValue(0, 3), aggTotal.getValue(0, 4), aggTotal.getValue(0, 5), null]);
                table.setDataTable(dt);
                table.draw();
                
                viewColumns.push({
                    calc: function (dt, row) {
                      var total = 0;
                      for (var c = 1; c < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
                        if (dt.getColumnLabel(c) !== 'Total') {
                          total += dt.getValue(row, c);
                        }
                      }
                      return total.toFixed(0);
                    },
                    role: 'annotation',
                    type: 'string'
                  });
                
                // create agg data view to add annotation
                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(agg);
                view.setColumns(viewColumns);
                view = view.toDataTable();
                for (var vc = 0; vc < view.getNumberOfColumns(); vc++) {
                  var viewLabel = view.getColumnLabel(vc);
                  for (var ac = 0; ac < agg.getNumberOfColumns(); ac++) {
                    var aggLabel = agg.getColumnLabel(ac);
                    if (viewLabel === aggLabel) {
                      view.setColumnLabel(vc, viewLabel + ' (' + aggTotal.getFormattedValue(0, ac) + ')');
                    }
                  }
                }
                
                // draw chart
                columnchrt.setDataTable(view);
                columnchrt.draw();

                google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', calcTotals);
              
                
            }


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Company', 'Grade1', 'Grade2', 'Grade3', 'Bal-Grade', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['NYC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 13, 5, 19, 29],
    ['CALI', 'ORG', 270, 210, 0, 32, 51, 60],
    ['CALI', 'CUSTOMERS', 35.942, 39, 0, 50, 126, 150],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 35, 52, 88, 100],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 44.507, 0, 25, 18, 88, 110],
    ['NJ', 'ORG', 0, 0, 54, 22, 28, 45],
    ['TXS', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 20]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker,categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_division" style="clear:left; display:inline-block; width:100%; float:left; margin-top:5px;">

<div class="float_left panel" style="float:left; width:50%; padding:0px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="float_left panel" style="width:50%; padding:0px;">
    <div class="table_bbar" style="background-color:#27ae60;" >
        <div id="categoryPicker_div" style="right:15px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div1" ></div>
    </div>

    <div id="table_div"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the total row for the table chart,
we can use a `modifier` function in the aggregation.

we aggregate once by location,
then again in total.

the modifier function allows us to return the same value for every row,
thus giving us the total for all rows.

then we can add the results from the total agg to the location agg.

```
// aggregate data table
var agg = google.visualization.data.group(
  dt,
  [0],
  aggColumns
);
var aggTotal = google.visualization.data.group(
  dt,
  [{
    column: 0,
    label: 'Total',
    modifier: function (val) {
      return 'Total';
    },
    type: 'string'
  }],
  aggColumns
);
var rowIndex = agg.addRow();
for (var i = 0; i < agg.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
  agg.setValue(rowIndex, i, aggTotal.getValue(0, i));
}
```

then we can use the agg total data table to set the labels in the column chart legend.

```
// create agg data view to add annotation
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(agg);
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
view = view.toDataTable();
for (var vc = 0; vc < view.getNumberOfColumns(); vc++) {
  var viewLabel = view.getColumnLabel(vc);
  for (var ac = 0; ac < agg.getNumberOfColumns(); ac++) {
    var aggLabel = agg.getColumnLabel(ac);
    if (viewLabel === aggLabel) {
      view.setColumnLabel(vc, viewLabel + ' (' + aggTotal.getFormattedValue(0, ac) + ')');
    }
  }
}
```

one other slight change, since we are re-drawing the charts inside the `'ready'` event,
we must use a one time event, else we'll go into an endless loop.

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', calcTotals);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  drawMainDashboard();
});

function drawMainDashboard() {
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
  document.getElementById('dashboard_division1'));

  var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 1,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Company Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
  'containerId': 'categoryPicker_div1',
  'options': {
    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
    'ui': {
      'labelStacking': 'vertical',
      'label': 'Location Selection:',
      'allowTyping': false,
      'allowMultiple': false
    }
  }
  });

  var columnchrt = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
  'containerId': 'chart_div',
  'options': {
       title: "Locations  charts",
       width: 850,
       height: 500,
       legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 2 },
       bar: { groupWidth: '70%' },
       isStacked: true,
       explorer: {keepInBounds: true, maxZoomIn: 10.0}
  }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  'chartType': 'Table',
  'containerId': 'table_div',
  'options': {
      showRowNumber: true,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      allowHtml: true
  },
  'view': {'columns': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', calcTotals);

  function calcTotals() {
    // get filtered data table from table chart
    var dt = table.getDataTable();

    // build aggregation and view columns
    var aggColumns = [];
    var viewColumns = [0];
    for (var i = 2; i < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 1) {
        if (dt.getColumnType(i) === 'number') {
          if (dt.getColumnRole(i) !== 'annotation') {
            addAggColumn(i);
            if (i !== dt.getNumberOfColumns() - 2) {
              viewColumns.push(i - 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    function addAggColumn(index) {
      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index,
        label: dt.getColumnLabel(index),
        type: dt.getColumnType(index)
      });
    }

    // aggregate data table
    var agg = google.visualization.data.group(
      dt,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );
    var aggTotal = google.visualization.data.group(
      dt,
      [{
        column: 0,
        label: 'Total',
        modifier: function (val) {
          return 'Total';
        },
        type: 'string'
      }],
      aggColumns
    );

    dt = dt.toDataTable();
    dt.addRow(['Total', '--', aggTotal.getValue(0, 1), aggTotal.getValue(0, 2), aggTotal.getValue(0, 3), aggTotal.getValue(0, 4), aggTotal.getValue(0, 5), null]);
    table.setDataTable(dt);
    table.draw();

    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var c = 1; c < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
          if (dt.getColumnLabel(c) !== 'Total') {
            total += dt.getValue(row, c);
          }
        }
        return total.toFixed(0);
      },
      role: 'annotation',
      type: 'string'
    });

    // create agg data view to add annotation
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(agg);
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);
    view = view.toDataTable();
    for (var vc = 0; vc < view.getNumberOfColumns(); vc++) {
      var viewLabel = view.getColumnLabel(vc);
      for (var ac = 0; ac < agg.getNumberOfColumns(); ac++) {
        var aggLabel = agg.getColumnLabel(ac);
        if (viewLabel === aggLabel) {
          view.setColumnLabel(vc, viewLabel + ' (' + aggTotal.getFormattedValue(0, ac) + ')');
        }
      }
    }

    // draw chart
    columnchrt.setDataTable(view);
    columnchrt.draw();

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(table, 'ready', calcTotals);
  }


  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Location', 'Company', 'Grade1', 'Grade2', 'Grade3', 'Bal-Grade', 'Total', { role: 'annotation' } ],
    ['NYC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 13, 5, 19, 19],
    ['CALI', 'ORG', 270, 210, 0, 32, 51, 51],
    ['CALI', 'CUSTOMERS', 35.942, 39, 0, 50, 126, 126],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 35, 52, 88, 88],
    ['WDC', 'CUSTOMERS', 44.507, 0, 25, 18, 88, 88],
    ['NJ', 'ORG', 0, 0, 54, 22, 28, 28],
    ['TXS', 'CUSTOMERS', 0, 0, 0, 10, 11, 11]
  ]);

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker,categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_division" style="clear:left; display:inline-block; width:100%; float:left; margin-top:5px;">

<div class="float_left panel" style="float:left; width:50%; padding:0px;">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
<div class="float_left panel" style="width:50%; padding:0px;">
    <div class="table_bbar" style="background-color:#27ae60;" >
        <div id="categoryPicker_div" style="right:15px; position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id="categoryPicker_div1" ></div>
    </div>

    <div id="table_div"></div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ofcourse that helps alot... so much... well do you see in graph that Total bar also showing.. its not suppose to come in there. only the locations should show, not Total Bar in chart. and if the locations count comes more than 10 ... the Total goes to second page of table.

Comment: sorry the second column [company] also not showing in table chart

Comment: hi thanks, works like charm... as expected. hope this post right place to ask related  to this topic.. if possible can be done which i added 3rd picture in this post above... about Bar annotation...

Comment: try adding following options --> `aggregationTarget: 'category'` -- & -- `tooltip: {showColorCode: true}`

Comment: thanks, these two lines met the requirement -- > focusTarget: 'category' 
 -- & -- aggregationTarget: 'category',...

Comment: is there anyway we can have the Total Row as a Static like footer of the table.. cuz if we have a more than 10 rows... Total Rows goes to second paging... cant we have like header not movable table...

Comment: you could draw a second table chart under the other with just the total row

Comment: thanks, and is it possible to have the different total values in Graph Label total and Grades Tooltip total. like fourth picture in this post which i edited.

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, again a question. that how can i get my 8th column as column chart Annotation? but i dont want to display this in my Table. only in Column chart.